# extraneous argument label 'path:' in call

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to swift and xcode and I am getting this error when I insert a labeled argument into `Zip.quickUnzipFile` method.
[image]
when I remove the `extraneous argument label`, I get this:
[image]
I am using the [Zip](https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip) library for swift.

Comment: Clicking on the link leads you to the solution of the first issue (in the section *Quick Functions*). To solve the second issue ⌃⌘-click on `URL` and compare the `init` methods. The proper `init` method depends on if the url is a remote or file system URL

Comment: ⌃⌘-click on `URL` but it brought me to the foundations library with not constructor defintions. This would be a file system path String.

Comment: is `URL(url)` of type `URL` or `URL?`? If it's `URL?` it might explain why it can't find the proper method.

Comment: Then press ⇧⌘0 (zero not O) and type URL (make sure Swift is selected) in the search field and select `URL`. Read there the `init` methods. A developer must be get used to read the documentation.

Comment: ... or use code completion. Delete `URL(url)`. Then re-type `URL(` and see what Xcode suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is classic Xcode "giving you a bogus error that hides the real error." Those errors are bogus.

There are two problems here though, but neither are the ones Xcode is giving you.

1. You need to either wrap your throwing method in a do/catch, or you need to put a `?` or a `!` after `try`.
2. The string initializer for URL is an optional initializer, and that method you're calling can't take in an initializer. Make sure to unwrap with optional chaining first.
3. URL requires an argument label 'string' in its initializer.

I don't know the context, but something like:

```
guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
  return
}
let unzipDirectory = try? Zip.quickUnzipFile(url)
```

Comment: You'll get the same error. There is no `init` method without parameter label in Swift 3+.

Comment: Nevertheless it doesn't help. According to a comment of the OP the URL is a file system URL so it's the wrong `init` method.

Comment: URL is http/local agnostic. You shouldn't need a different initializer if the path is correct.

Comment: *You should*. For a file system URL (the parameter is a string path starting with `/`) you **have to** use `URL(fileURLWithPath`. The `file://` scheme is added implicitly. The `URL(string` initializer is for url strings including the scheme.

Comment: Ah. Yeah. You’re right. But under the hood, that initializer is using the string one. You could easily prepend “file://“ but you’re right, no need to reinvent the wheel when there’s something already in place.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `url` like below and then pass it to `quickUnzipFile`

```
if let url = URL(string: url) {
    try Zip.quickUnzipFile(url)
}
```